# How to filter a list in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: list, filter, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I'm filtering a list of stocks by symbol, but it doesn't work. Maybe there's something wrong with the code? Something I have missed? Here are some of things I've tried:

```js
function filterBySymbol: function(select, value) {

    var ordersStore = this.getBrokerageOrderHistoryList().getStore();

    ordersStore.clearFilter();

    if (value !== '') {
        ordersStore.data.filterBy(function (record, id) {
            // log to make certain this gets called (and it is)
            console.log(id, record.get('symbol') === value);
            return record.get('symbol') === value;
        });

// Other things I've tried (nothing worked):
// 1)
//          var f = new Ext.util.Filter({
//             filterFn: function(record) {
//                return record.get('symbol') === value;
//             }
//          });
//          ordersStore.filterBy(f);
// 2)
//          ordersStore.filter(function (record) {
//              return record.get('symbol') === value;
//          });
// 3)
//          this.getBrokerageOrderHistoryList().setStore(ordersStore);
//          this.getBrokerageOrderHistoryList().refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out we had to disable remote filtering on the store, which is supposed to default to false, but it wasn't:

```
this.getOrderList().getStore().setRemoteFilter(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

one of these should work

```
// 1
ordersStore.filter("symbol", value);

// 2
ordersStore.filter([    
    { filterFn: function(item) { return item.get("symbol") === value; }}
]);

// 3
ordersStore.filterBy(function(item) { 
return item.get("symbol") === value; 
}
```

**UPDATE:** sample that works:

```
Ext.define('ST.store.Products', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        fields: ["title", "category" ],
        storeId: "Products",

        data: [
            { title: 'Text1', category: 'cat1'},
            { title: 'Text2', category: 'cat2'},
            { title: 'Text3', category: 'cat3'},
        ]
    }
});

 console.log("before");
        Ext.getStore("Products").each(function(item){
            console.log(item.data.title);

        });        

        Ext.getStore("Products").filterBy(function(item){
            return item.get('title') == 'Text1';    
        });

        console.log("after");
        var store = Ext.getStore("Products").each(function(item){
            console.log(item.data.title);

        });
```

in my case I see the following in the developer console

```
before 
Text1
Text2
Text3
after
Text1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these work. the lambda passed to orderStore.filterBy never gets called. It does get called if passed to orderStore.data.filterBy. The filterFn doesn't get called either. No sure about the first method, but list contents don't change :\

Comment: Seems like you have configured your store incorrect. I updated post with sample, it works

Comment: Thanks for that. You are probably right. I have a model and a store for it, and that model has a hasMany property, pointing to another model. I guess, I should create a store for the model that hasMany property refers to as well.